# Android Navigation Drawer Getting Data From Server

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, server, navigation-drawer

**I need to create an Android application consisting of a drawer menu the fragments of which get data from server.**

- I don't have any experience related to server-side programming, so I
  need to know which is the most rational way of completing the task.
  If you know a link to some tutorials, which explain the above
  mentioned process step by step > please provide me the URL to those
  tutorials, I've searched for several hours and didn't find an exact
  explanation.

*I am relatively new to Android Development and I have to complete a task in the upcoming 24 hours, so please give me a detailed explanation of the steps or at least some advises concerning this task > I'll be extremely thankful for that!*

**Thank you so much!!!**

Comment: Have you implements drawer menu with fragments?

Comment: Yes, now I am interested in how to set fragments to get data from server. I'd like to get a link to a tutorial for understanding the whole process or do get some advises. @riazhasan

Comment: u solved it? If yes upvote my answer too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this class for downloading your data.Then update your UI.

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       //do your http request here

        return result;//what you got from server
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

 //process your result and update ui here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}
```

then call the task using

```
new LongOperation.execute();
```

call it from your onCreateView function before return statement.

Comment: thank you mate! So there is no need for using any other language for server-side programming, right?
And I need to add the code mentioned by you in the fragments parts (i.e. switches/cases)? @riazhasan

Comment: you have to send an http request for fetching the data.then have to update.But what do you mean by serverside programming?